# Game Engine: Cube won't move on negative x

Tags: game-engine, physics

In the Blender Game Engine, I used servo control to move a cube along the x axis when "W" was pressed. That worked fine, but when I used the exact same settings (except for direction, of course) to make it move on the negative x axis when "S" was pressed, it wouldn't move. I even tried changing the direction to the positive x, and that worked fine. But when I switched it back, it didn't work again. And I don't think that it is because of directional friction, because this same thing happens when it is on a different platform, or even in midair. Also, it works fine when I don't give it an x limit, but even if I give it a limit of 10000 it wont budge. And I really need that limit on it. Does anybody know why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: you also has to set the limit force min to -10000 (the force will be negative for backward movement)

Comment: @Chebhou Add as answer so we get this off the kill list :D

Comment: My phrase... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are moving the Object in the negative direction ( -X ) you need to set the minimum limit instead of the maximum and it should be negative as the force applied on the object will be negative :

[image]